# ¿ De que forma puedo recorrer el vector?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre toda la información de todos los Clientes usando un `Vector`?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AgregarClientes {

    public AgregarClientes() {
        Vector vector = new Vector();

        Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
        clientes.setNombre(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el nombre"));
        clientes.setApellido(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el apellido"));
        clientes.setIdentificacion(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la identificacion")));
        clientes.setTelefono(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el telefono")));
        clientes.setTipocliente(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de cliente")));
        clientes.setTipocliente(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de vehiculo")));
        clientes.setHoras(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de horas")));
        clientes.setPlaca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la placa del vehiculo"));       
        vector.addElement(clientes);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sería útil que indicaras que version de java usas

Comment: Es la version 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero para el uso de esa coleccion te recomiendo especificar el tipo de datos que va a contener, esto se hace asi

```
Vector<Clientes> vector = new Vector<Clientes>();
```

y si tienes java 8 se puede inferir el segundo parámetro

```
Vector<Clientes> vector = new Vector<>();
```

Una forma es con el **for mejorado** se puede usar a partir de Java 1.7.

El for mejorado es de la siguiente forma

```
for(TipoDeDatos cualquierNombreDeVariable:nombreDeColeccion){
       System.out.println(cualquierNombreDeVariable.getCampo());
}
```

tu colección debe de implementar la interfaz iterable, y es el caso de Vector.

tu código quedaría:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AgregarClientes {

    public AgregarClientes() {
        Vector<Clientes> vector = new Vector<Clientes>();

        Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
        clientes.setNombre(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el nombre"));
        clientes.setApellido(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el apellido"));
        clientes.setIdentificacion(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la identificacion")));
        clientes.setTelefono(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el telefono")));
        clientes.setTipocliente(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de cliente")));
        clientes.setTipocliente(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tipo de vehiculo")));
        clientes.setHoras(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el numero de horas")));
        clientes.setPlaca(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la placa del vehiculo"));       
        vector.addElement(clientes);


     for(Clientes cliente:vector){
       System.out.println(cliente.getNombre());
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: No hay de que. Hay varias formas pero pensé que esta es la que es más amigable.